# Namespace collision within R's subset() function

Tags: r, namespaces, subset

I've stumble across the following namespace problem with R's subset function so many times, that I would like to ask for a more elegant solution than mine here:

```
Species <- 'setosa'
subset(iris, Species==Species)
```

returns the entire `iris` dataset, I think because `Species==Species` evaluates to true.

My solution would be

```
subset(iris, Species==get('Species', envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

but this would not work when the variable `Species` is only defined within the scope of a function.

It would of course also be possible to use a different variable name like `species` (lowercase) for the global variable.
However, I think this would actually be less readable and as a end user I would actually expect `R` to allow this kind of comparison of two variables with the same name from different namespaces.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Note the **Warning** in the `?subset` documentation: *"This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument `subset` can have unanticipated consequences."* `subset` was a very early foray into non-standard evaluation. Packages that came later like `data.table`, and **much** later like `dplyr`, build on the non-standard evaluation ideas and refine it to a point where it is ready for  programmatic use, with clear ways to handle cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base R `subset` function simply does not handle the case of identical variable names well. I think that's one of the reasons the `subset` help page contains the following warning

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.

That message is basically suggesting you use

```
iris[iris$Species==Species, ]
```

An alternative to the `get()` would be to use the `globalenv()` function to get the global environment

```
subset(iris, Species==globalenv()$Species)
```

If you are using dplyrs `filter()` function, there is a way to be explicit with the `.env` pronoun

```
dplyr::filter(iris, Species==.env$Species)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, which was very helpful for me. I always thought that the square bracket syntax would be provided for convenience as an alternative to the `subset()` function. Good to know that it's actually the other way around.

Comment: we might also define `.env <- environment()` in the function and then we can use dplyr's syntax with `subset()` too. `iris[iris$Species==Species, ]` might return something different in case Species is NA on one either side.